# A problem with a application of SLLN and CLT and distribution convergence

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $Y_{i}\overset{i.i.d}{\sim} N(0,\sigma^{2})$ with $\sigma^{2}$ unknow. I'm trying to prove that $$
>     \sqrt{n}\left(\overline{Y}_{n}^{2}- \sigma^2 \right) \overset{D}{\to}  N\left(0,2\sigma^4\right)$$

**My approach:** I proved that $\overline{Y}_{n}^{2}\overset{D}{\to} \sigma^{2}$ using the strong law large number and using the central limit theorem for random variables i.i.d we have that $\sqrt{n}(\overline{Y}_{n}-\mathbb{E}X_{i})\overset{D}{\to} N(0,\sigma^{2})$, then I was trying use that fact that $f(x)=x^{2}$ and apply the Delta's method, but I can't continue from here because $f(x)=[\mathbb{E}X_{i}]^{2}=0$ and I obtained $\sqrt{n}\overline{Y}_{n}^{2}\overset{D}{\to}N(0,0)$ but its not
desired. 1) *How can I solve this problem from here?* *and can I use that result for conclude that $\overline{Y}_{n}^{2}$ is consistent for $\sigma^{2}$?* **Note:** I proved that $\overline{Y}_{n}^{2}$ is consistent without that result above, but also I'm trying to see if I can conclude the same using the result above.

Comment: If $\overline Y_n^2=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2$ (which is bad notation since this is not square of the sample mean $\overline Y_n$), then this is a direct application of CLT.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes $\overline{Y}_{n}^{2}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i}^{2}$ and I was trying to use the CLT but as I said I don't know how  I can use that in this problem.

Comment: CLT says $\sqrt n\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i}^{2}-\operatorname E(Y_1^2)\right)\stackrel{d}\to N(0,\operatorname{Var}(Y_1^2))$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom are you apply the CLT to $Y^{2}$ is correct and not to $Y$? Uhm...

Comment: Yes $\space$...

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ok, I understand and I know that $\mathbb{E}X_{i}^{2}=\mathbb{V}X_{i}+[\mathbb{E}X_{i}]^{2}=\sigma^{2}-\mu^{2}=\sigma^{2}$ but $\mathbb{V}X_{i}^{2}=\mathbb{E}X_{i}^{4}-[\mathbb{E}X_{i}]^{2}$ how can I continue  from here?

Answer (score 1):

there are various ways to approach the problem.

The first I get in mind is the more statistical one.

Just to avoid misunderstandings, let's set

$$Y_i \sim N(0;\theta)$$

where $\theta=\sigma^2$

First observe that $T=\overline{Y}_n^2$ is the maximum likelihood estimator for $\sigma^2$ thus is is well known (it is one important property of MLE that you can check in any basic Statistics Textbooks) that

$$\sqrt{I_n(\theta)}\Big(\overline{Y}_n^2-\theta\Big)\dot{\sim}N[0;1]$$

Where $I_n(\theta)$ is the Fischer Information.

$$I_n(\theta)=-nE\Bigg\{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}\log f(x,\theta)\Bigg\}$$

---

Calculations...

---

$$f(x,\theta)\propto \theta^{-1/2}e^{-y^2/(2\theta)}$$

$$\log f(x,\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}\log\theta-\frac{y^2}{2\theta}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(x,\theta)=-\frac{1}{2\theta}+\frac{y^2}{2\theta^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\theta^2}-\frac{y^2}{\theta^3}$$

$$\mathbb{E}\Bigg[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(x,\theta)\Bigg]=\frac{1}{2\theta^2}-\frac{\theta}{\theta^3}=-\frac{1}{2\theta^2}$$

$$-n\mathbb{E}\Bigg[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(x,\theta)\Bigg]=\frac{n}{2\theta^2}=\frac{n}{2\sigma^4}$$

---

This means that

$$\overline{Y}_n^2\dot{\sim}N\Bigg(\sigma^2;\frac{2\sigma^4}{n}\Bigg)$$

Your are all set!